# Cocoa WebView: can I load web and local resources together in the same page?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

This is just a generic questions about Cocoa WebView on OSX.

Given the problems I had with the BaseURL settings in my web view (I can only set it as `local` or `https://)`, I'm wondering if I can load in the same webView both local and online resources.

Let's say including in the html page some images from the local file system and some videos from youtube.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to load online resourses or a local html file in your bundle to a webView.

```
self.mutableRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myawesomeapp.com"]];
/*self.mutableRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourHtmlResource" ofType:@"html"]]];*/
[self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:self.mutableRequest];
```

Comment: But did it use to work in the past? I had no problems with loading local and online resources (youtube) in the past. (Probably more than 1 year ago for sure on Mavericks.. not sure on which APIs version.

Comment: If I reload the webView with local/online resources as you say, the webView is gonna be always incomplete, correct? (For example after loading the youtube video, I will get empty local images). I think that's not a solution.

Comment: Instead what do you mean with multiple webView? Can i embed a webView inside another webView?

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer? What does that code mean? More specifically, I need to load a Youtube video in my webpage with many local files and not just load a webpage in my web view.

Comment: Once a youtube video is embedded to your local webpage, it will be loaded in the webView as well.

Comment: But how do I embed the "local webpage" exactly in the same position, where my video now is in the html code? Can I specify a reference in the html code to load that page at that exact position in the page layout?

Comment: In other words, in your answer how to dynamically position self.webView inside my html page? That's the tricky part to solve, not just loading a webpage into a web view programmatically.